# YQL Google Search inconsistent results

Tags: yql

I'm using YQL to retrieve site specific results (I don't need Google results for just my own site but for a variety of sites.

However, I'm getting inconsistent results. Using the YQL console for my query:

- Executing a Test for the same query multiple times, sometimes returns result but quite often gives no result without producing an error.
- When there are results, the number of results is often significantly less from manually executing a Google query on google.com

An example query that shows this behaviour is
select * from google.search where q = 'site:www.freelas.net'

Any suggestions on this?

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older Google Search API that the `google.search` YQL table uses has been deprecated by Google. It's still running, but I think there is a 100 query/day limit. When you see no results in YQL console, it likely means that it's being rate-limited.

As an alternative you might try using the newer [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). Note that it's only free up to 100 queries/day, but they offer a paid plan above that.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that also. It just seems terribly inconsistent to return what seems like a valid result that is essentially invalid.